# How to parse non standard date formate in R

Tags: r, date, parsing

I am trying to parse a date string like 1/12/2014 which represents the first of december 2014. However, looking at http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html it looks like R would only support parsing something like 01/12/2014. Is this correct? How could I parse the date mentioned above?

**Update: I used y instead of Y for the year and the date got parsed as "2020-12-01" --> everything working fine now.**

Comment: No, that is not correct, as can easily be determined by the simplest of experiments: `as.Date("1/12/2014", format="%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: damn I used a lower case y and in resulted in 2020-12-01. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

```
as.Date("1/12/2014", format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

See the Details section of `?strptime` for an extensive list of the components of date-time that R can format.

Comment: damn I used a lower case y and in resulted in 2020-12-01. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

lubridate makes handling dates easy. Use `dmy` for dates in day-month-year format.

```
library(lubridate)
dmy("1/12/2014")
```